# problem with the connectivity/updation using db2(universal driver)

Tags: db2-connect

I choosed a web project in order to do that i am using an IDE (Eclipse), database (DB2 universal driver) and Apache Tomcat server. So, by gods grace every thing has gone well but when I try to update data to DB2 database through JDBC code then I am getting an SQL DB error as

```
:: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC: DB2ADMIN.REGISTER
```

where register is my table name and even i logged in as db2admin but i think there is no connectivity established but still its not resolved

Comment: Can you paste in the JDBC code snippet?

Comment: @rams - I mean the SQL statement you are trying to run

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit strange, -204 is Function, procedure or trigger not found...

Have a look at [SQLCODE concepts](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzala/rzalaco.htm) and use the SQL Message Finder link to check yr return code for a full explanation.

Note that DB2 procedures & functions have case-sensitive names.

Hope this helps.